# WIFI not getting open when application in KIOSK Mode. Wear OS

Tags: android, kotlin, wear-os, kiosk-mode, samsung-galaxy

I am developing a KIOSK Mode stand alone application for Wear OS(Samsung Watch 4, Wear OS 3.5). For KIOSK mode I am using device owner permission using ADB and used device `[DevicePolicyManager][1]` class to handle hardware button and status bar etc.

**My Issue is, I am not able to open System WIFI settings which navigate to outside of KIOSK mode.**

Just for your information I can open system bluetooth settings without disabling KIOSK mode. One more information: case 3 code work perfectly if your KIOSK mode is disable

I tried:

**Case1.**

```kotlin
context.startActivity(Intent("com.google.android.clockwork.settings.connectivity.wifi.ADD_NETWORK_SETTINGS"))
```

*I can see something gets opened and closed automatically.*

**Case 2.**

```kotlin
val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS)
intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
startActivity(intent)
```

**Case 3.**

```kotlin
startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS))
```

If any one have any idea or workaround. Much appreciate your inputs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I achieved it by whitelisted packagename.

```kotlin
devicePolicyManager!!.setLockTaskPackages(deviceAdmin, arrayOf("our.own.package.name","com.google.android.apps.wearable.settings"))
```

After whitelisted in KIOSK mode. now it will work!

```kotlin
startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS))
```